# Tool to catch missing div?

Tags: html

Are there any tool out there to check if our `HTML` code is missing any `div`. Or is there a method to do this easily without losing temper and getting frustrated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) will check for a number of problems. If you have a `</div>` without a matching `<div>`, it will pick it up.